# parent page set vertical scrollbar to top after close jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, dialog

I use jQuery v.1.8.2 and jQuery UI v.1.9.0 (sorry i can't change version because it co-project)
When i use dialog like this

```
var _content = '<div>some html</div>';
var _dialogObj = $(_content).dialog();
```

and close it by call

```
$(_dialogObj).dialog('close');
```

Dialog work perfectly fine, it closed.

But my problem is here. After closed it set my parent page to the top of page by scrolling vertical scrollbar. I want to fix it at the same position before dialog open not jump to the top like that.
**PS** I'm not sure that because of my coding style or not? 
I use ajax call to generic handler (.ashx file) in C# that they return html code and then i push it in to div tag to generate my web page. That mean my init page just have only nav tag.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with this problem? So, we could see  and help. Because this problem seems to be no related to the plugin itself but something you do around it.

Comment: Sorry to late reply, my problem is i use <a> to call dialog so i change it to <span> and it solved. Thank.